# Apply a condition on specific column data - jquery DataTable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datatables

Firstly, I have the following table:

[image]
The column which enclosed by red color display 2 types of account, the value `1`= `Free` and value `2` = `paid` (free, paid accounts).

I want before rendering the data, apply a condition to change the `1` to `free` and `2` to `paid`.

that's it.

**Table initialization:**

```
var dataTableY = $('#table').DataTable({
    serverSide: true,
    ajax: {
        url: 'directory/class/method'
    },
    processing: true,
    scrollY: 400,
    paging: true,
    info: true,
    select: {
        style: 'os'
    },
    pagingType: 'full_numbers',
    language: {
        url: 'DataTables/lang/english.json'
    }
});
```

Comment: do you use a JSON source or is this a plain HTML <table> you just convert to a dataTable? Please show you you initialise the dataTable.

Comment: You dont have any `columns` or `columnDefs` definition? Anyway, use the `columnDefs` in the answer below.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Use a [**column renderer**](https://datatables.net/examples/advanced_init/column_render.html) :

```
var table = $('#example').dataTable({
    //...
    columnDefs : [
        { targets : [4],
          render : function (data, type, row) {
             return data == '1' ? 'free' : 'paid'
          }
        }
   ]
})
```

The render function will return `'free'` if the column value is 1, otherwise `'paid'`. You could use a `switch` if you have more values, or for example need to return a `'N/A'` too.

---

```
    columnDefs : [
        { targets : [4],
          render : function (data, type, row) {
            switch(data) {
               case '1' : return 'free'; break;
               case '2' : return 'paid'; break;
               default  : return 'N/A';
            }
          }
        }
   ]
```

Comment: Thank you, Can you please give me another example for switch statement.

Comment: @davidkonrad , i used both with no luck, i used true false value , but it always fails data == 'true' ? '<span>ok</span>' : '<span>no</span>', any idea what could be missing

Comment: @Dragon, hard to say with no info; "*no luck*" means `render` returns nothing, ok or no? The problem is either your data or your evaluation.  A scenario could be that your data holds `'1'` instead of `'true'`. That would be the case if a server script blindly loads rows from a mysql table containing boolean fields.

Comment: @davidkonrad its sql server and in db it is saved as bit , but in code it would be true,false, that didnot work with datatable , but when i sent data to datatable in the form of 1 and 0 then its working fine, don't know whats the issue , but its working in case of 1,0

Comment: @davidkonrad, It's working perfectly for single value but what if I have to display more then one in the same cell? like now the switch(data) is talking only one value in case I have to display like "free and cancel" both then? free=1 and cancel= -1

Comment: @davidkonrad Just what I was looking for, thank you very much!