# How to properly specify the visibility of a column based on an event?

Tags: javascript, datatables

I want to hide column [12] in my table whenever the user clicks on the "reportTab" hyperlink,I'am using datatable. How can I do this using "visible" property in columnDefs?

I used the "addEventListener" in my javascript so when the user clicks the hyperlink I will set a boolean variable to true.  I found this question "[Apply a condition on specific column data - jquery DataTable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33192879/apply-a-condition-on-specific-column-data-jquery-datatable)" which is quite related to what I want to do because I'am looking for a way to set the visibility of a column based on a condition. I try following the answer of davidkonrad on this question, then I tried creating my logic for what I want to do. But for some reason it is not working. I'am new to js so I don't know if I'm doing everything right. The js is already rendered on the page where I want to do this.

I was expecting that when the user clicks on "reportTab" the column [12] will show, else it will be hidden. But not only it does not go hidden whenever "reportTab" is not clicked, it is showing this output "[object Object]" on the cells under column [12]. I want to do this because of relevance. Column [12] is not relevant to other tabs/hyperlink that is why I want to hide it.

````
var clicked = false;
document.getElementById("reportTab").addEventListener("click", function () {
        clicked = true;
});

```columnDefs
"targets": [12],
render: function () {
    return clicked === true ? { "visible": true, "targets": [12] } : { "visible": false, "targets": [12]};
}
````

Comment: Just use [`column().visible()` API](https://datatables.net/reference/api/column().visible()).

Comment: Thank you very much Alexander! This really a great help.

Comment: So I tried using this one but somehow I was not able produce the output that I want. Instead here is what I did:
`             
(eval(boolean_var) === true && eval(boolean_var) !== true) ? { "visible": false, "targets": [0, 2, 13, 12] } : { "visible": false, "targets": [0, 2, 13] },`

this one gave the output I want. But still thank you again Alexander. I'm just posting my work-around on my own problem for, maybe, reference someone else.

Answer (score 0):

Just use [`column().visible()`](https://datatables.net/reference/api/column().visible()) API within the click event handler.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#myTable').DataTable({
    columnDefs: [{
        targets: [2],
        visible: false
      }]
  });
});
$('#myButton').on('click', function() {
  $('#myTable').DataTable().column(2).visible(true);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<link href="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<table id="myTable">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Position</th>
      <th>Salary</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
      <td>System Architect</td>
      <td>$320,800</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Garrett Winters</td>
      <td>Accountant</td>
      <td>$170,750</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<button id="myButton">Click Me</button>
```

The third column is hidden by default. The button click makes the column is visible.