# How to display a text on a column data according to condition in jQuery DataTable?

Tags: jquery, if-statement, datatables

The column is_active has 2 types of value, value 1 should be equal to Active and value 2 should be equal to Inactive. Now I want to display Active or Inactive in the column according to a condition. How to do this?

**Table implementation**

```
function loadTemplates() {
        template_table = $('#template-table').DataTable({
            processing: true,
            serverSide: true,
            "ajax": {
                "url": 'template-table',
                "type": "POST",
                "data": function (d) {
                    d._token = "{{ csrf_token() }}";
                }
            },
            "aaSorting": [[0, 'desc']],
            "fnDrawCallback": function (oSettings) {
                rowHighlight('template-table');
                selectRowOnTableLoad(oSettings, 'id', selectedRowID);
                dataTableRow = oSettings;
            },
            columns: [
                {data: 'id'},
                {data: 'title'},
                {data: 'start_date'},
                {data: 'end_date'},
                {data: 'is_active'},//column need to be displayed a text
                {data: 'template_content'},               
                {data: 'action', orderable: false, searchable: false}
            ]
        });
    }
```

Comment: You can set that value on your server-side, like when sending an ajax call you can check on the server-side whether it's value.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Apply a condition on specific column data - jquery DataTable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33192879/apply-a-condition-on-specific-column-data-jquery-datatable)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Use [`render`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.render#Description) : This property will modify the data that is used by
>   DataTables for various operations as it is read from the data source

```
 columns: [
                    {data: 'id'},
                    {data: 'title'},
                    {data: 'start_date'},
                    {data: 'end_date'},
                    {data: 'is_active',
                     render: function (data, type, row) {
                        return `<span>${row.is_active==1 ? Active : Inactive}<span>`;
                       }
                       },//column need to be displayed a text
                    {data: 'template_content'},               
                    {data: 'action', orderable: false, searchable: false}


       ]
```